# IKDeviceBrowserView displays no contents on OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: cocoa, osx-mountain-lion, imagekit

I can't get rid of a bug with `IKDeviceBrowserView` in 10.8 with Xcode 4.4.

I've created new test project, put an `IKDeviceBrowserView` into my window, added Quartz.framework to link with. After building, I see a blank window. There are no warning/error/logs in console and no `IKDeviceBrowserView` in window.

I've tried setting different SDK, deployment target, and playing with autosizing, with no result.

It seems like Apple have broken `IKDeviceBrowserView` in 10.8.

Comment: Same here. Any progress? It seems that apps using device browser are non functional in 10.8 even if build with 10.6 SDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution: set your nib to use autolayout and set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `YES` to your `IKDeviceBrowserView`.

I hope this bug will be fixed soon.

Comment: Whether translating the autoresizing masks works depends on what you did when you placed and positioned the views under autolayout. A typical layout would be to set a horizontal spacing constraint between the two views, and have a width constraint only on the device browser. With a good layout, you don't need the translates code or any other code. Auto-layout takes some work to adopt, but it's worth it. (For me, I came to this question because I was expecting it to show the iSight camera, but of course it shows only connected cameras, which have camera rolls).