# Cocoa window not displaying properly (or at all) on newer OS

Tags: cocoa, osx-mountain-lion, ikscannerdeviceview

I developed a simple application that looks pretty much the same as Image Capture. I am using Quartz framework and `IKDeviceBrowserView` and `IKScannerDeviceView`.

When I test it on my iMac or macbook with OSX 10.7 it works fine, but when I tested on another macbooks the application is not displaying properly. One running 10.8.2 displays an empty gray window, the other running 10.8.1 displays a window and only the lower area is displayed.

I am completely new to Cocoa so I have no idea on what is going on or how to solve it. Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

EDIT: Everything is created using Interface Builder: I have a MainWindow and the two scanner views I mentioned above.

Comment: People will probably need a few clues about how you're creating/displaying your window content before they can even guess.

Comment: @PhillipMills Everything is added via IB on the MainWindow which is referenced on the Info.plist 'Main nib file base name' attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is actually a duplicate of [IKDeviceBrowserView displays no contents on OSX Mountain Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841349/ikdevicebrowserview-displays-no-contents-on-osx-mountain-lion) which I couldn't find before.

This issue is solved by setting `AutoLayout` on the nib and setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES` in both `IKDeviceBrowserView` and `IKScannerDeviceView`.